# How To Display Data Using Angular 4 Interceptors

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular4-httpclient

I'm new to Angular 4 interceptors and I'm trying to implement this in my application. All i wanted to do is if i have an 404 error or like if token expires it would navigate me to the login page. Also, my problem is that I how would i display my data in the html? I've already commented out my previous working example without the new http interceptor. Anyone who can help me display my data and when error occurs redirect me to the login page? I've posted my code below. Thanks.

> news.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class NewsService {
  newslist: any;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

 getAllNews() {

    // if(this.newslist != null) {
    //   return Observable.of(this.newslist);
    // } 

    // else {
      const authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token'); 
      const headers = new HttpHeaders() 
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json') 
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

    //   return this.httpClient
    //     .get('http://sample.com/news/', 
    //       { headers: headers })
    //     .map((response => response))
    //     .do(newslist => this.newslist = newslist)
    //     .catch(e => {
    //         if (e.status === 401) {
    //             return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');

    //         }

    //     });
    // }

    const req = new HttpRequest('GET', 'http://sample.com/news/', {reportProgress: true,  headers: headers  } )
    return this.httpClient.request(req);
  }

  getNews(id: number) { 
    return this.getAllNews().map((data:any)=> data.data.data.find(news => news.id === id)) 
  }

}
```

> news.interceptor.ts

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { NewsService } from './news.service';


@Injectable()
export class NewsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private newsService: NewsService){}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
        console.log("Intercepted!", req);
        const copiedReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers});
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear. What is "my data"? Where should it be displayed? There is no data to display anywhere if you get a 404. Also, show some research effort. Have you read the documentation? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @JBNizet. my data is the value from the .map((response => response)). Yes of course. I've tried to implement the interceptor.

Comment: This line of code is commented out. Even if it was not, it wouldn't do anything at all. And it wouldn't be called anyway if you have a 404.

Comment: @JBNizet. So how would i display the value of .map((response => response)) using the interceptor?

Comment: You don't seem to understand what an interceptor is for. An interceptor doesn't display anything. That's what components are for. An interceptor is used to intercept HTTP requests and responses. For example to add a header, or cache the response, or log errors, or redirect in case of a specific error.

Comment: @JBNizet. So where would i put the .map ?

Comment: You first need to understand what you want to do. Then read documentation. This is way too broad. You don't seem to understand what .map() does in the first place. Sorry, but this is way too broad.

Comment: I understand.I just want to know  where i to put  .map response